# Is there a way to automate expanding a navigation tree?

Tags: python, automation, scrapy

I have a web application at work and it's very dated and managed by a group I have no influence over.  But the site contains a ton of valuable info I want to mine.   I can get to it, but it's buried in an old-school left-side nav tree with about 1,000 items and anywhere from 1 to 7 layers deep.   I can scrape the source code to get the top level 1,000 items, but I'd have to click open every single item through all the layers to get at the data beneath that I really want.   Can python/scrapy automated expanding the whole tree?   Is there another way to automate this.   The site is behind 2FA and nothing is shown in the HTML unless you click into the javascript links in the nav tree.  I'm hoping there's a way to do this if I have the site already open on my desktop?   Any ideas?  The links I need to open automatically are like this:

```
<img src="data:image/gif;base64,asasdsfsdasdafs" class=" x-tree-elbow-img x-tree-elbow-plus x-tree-expander">
```

Comment: You can probably get this to work using a library like `selenium` and a browser driver for it. The main issue would be the 2FA, but depending on the kind, you can probably add something to the script that inserts the 2FA response (like the sms message, authenticator code, etc.) after the script starts. The type of browser that selenium drives executes the JavaScript like a regular browser, so you can manipulate the page like you would in a regular browser.

Comment: Thank you, @grismar !   This is a great solution.  I've gotten most of the solution figured out.  just a few more things to work out.

Comment: You're welcome - if you've got a working solution and know what steps you'd need to take to reproduce, you can consider writing the answer to your own question. That may seem a bit self-involved, but it's actually something that helpful to others. I didn't write an answer since I only provided a suggestion, but if you think you've cracked it, please do.

Comment: I got it. Works perfectly -- any advice on better coding?  https://stackoverflow.com/a/64002547/5415980

Comment: Added a comment, but no - I think you solved it well enough to use and more effort would just be needless polish.