# How to identify this element with Selenium and use element.click() with a number variable

Tags: python, selenium

I've got most of this solution figured out, but can't get my head around this one (I'm new to this BTW).

I've got a site with an expandable nav tree in a frame and I need to expand all the elements in it and then extract the resulting text.

Below is the basic pattern I'm working with.   As I click on an element (class=" x-tree-elbow-img x-tree-elbow-plus x-tree-expander"), it will open up the next one below and increment all the "data-recordindex" attributes.

To start with, the first data-recordindex is "0" and all other items are under it. It's already expanded/open, so I have to skip this one, or I'll click on it and collapse everything and none of the code will remain to search.    If I can then start at data-recordindex = "1" and click that, then wait for the code to generate and move on the "2" and so on.   My tree goes up to data-recordindex = "1083" in the starting state.  Expanding it fully from the top down will likely result in over 50k records, so adding a wait to each click will be time consuming.    Once it's expanded, I'm able to capture all the text.

I think I should find the  tag containing data-recordindex="1" and then within that , find the  with the class containing "expander" and click on it.  Then wait for the code to generate and go back though the loop incrementing the find to data-record index to "2" and so on until I've run out of data-recordindexes to find.   When that's done, It'll be fully expanded and I can start another process to print out all the text.

I know I'm not using the count variable right in the first find because it's kicking out an error.  I also assume that once I find the first  section, my search for the expander link will work just because it will find the first one it comes to and click on it.

Here's the loop part of the script and below it is representative section of the HTML.

BTW, thanks to @Grismar for letting me know Selenium exists!

'''

### I don't know how many loops I'll need, so I just picked a big number, I'm sure there's a better way to do this -- like just do until or something

```
N = 1000000

for counter in range(N):

    counter = counter + 1
```

### if I hardcode this to data-recordindex = "2" it finds the right record.  I just need to pass the counter value into that spot

```
    datarecord = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(@data-recordindex,'+counter+')]")
```

### This find and click works, but it's not restricting the find to start at the tag that datarecord is at

```
    link = datarecord.find_element_by_xpath("//img[contains(@class,'expander')]")

    link.click()
```

### sample of the HTML code I'm searching

```
    <tbody id="treeview-1131-body">
                    
        <tr role="row" id="treeview-1131-record-9770" data-boundview="treeview-1131" data-recordid="9770"
            data-recordindex="0" class="x-grid-row x-grid-tree-node-expanded x-grid-data-row" tabindex="-1"> 
            
            <td role="gridcell"
                class="x-grid-cell x-grid-td x-grid-cell-treecolumn-1129 x-grid-cell-treecolumn x-grid-cell-first x-unselectable x-grid-cell-treecolumn"
                id="ext-gen13417">
                <div unselectable="on" class="x-grid-cell-inner x-grid-cell-inner-treecolumn"
                    style="text-align:left;"><img
                        src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw=="
                        class=" x-tree-elbow-img x-tree-elbow-end-plus x-tree-expander"><img
                        src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw=="
                        class=" x-tree-icon x-tree-icon-parent x-tree-node-noicon"><span
                        class="x-tree-node-text ">Text to extract 1</span>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td role="gridcell"
                class="x-grid-cell x-grid-td x-grid-cell-actioncolumn-1130 x-grid-cell-last x-unselectable  x-action-col-cell"
                id="ext-gen13418">
                <div unselectable="on" class="x-grid-cell-inner x-grid-cell-inner-action-col"
                    style="text-align:left;"><img role="button" alt=""
                        src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw=="
                        class="x-action-col-icon x-action-col-0   x-tree-search"
                        data-qtip="L:eccng.widget.tree_search_tooltip"></div>
            </td>
        </tr>   
           
        <tr role="row" id="treeview-1131-record-1490622" data-boundview="treeview-1131" data-recordid="1490622"
            data-recordindex="1" class="x-grid-row x-grid-tree-node-expanded x-grid-data-row" tabindex="-1">
            <td role="gridcell"
                class="x-grid-cell x-grid-td x-grid-cell-treecolumn-1129 x-grid-cell-treecolumn x-grid-cell-first x-unselectable x-grid-cell-treecolumn"
                id="ext-gen15793">
                <div unselectable="on" class="x-grid-cell-inner x-grid-cell-inner-treecolumn"
                    style="text-align:left;"><img
                        src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw=="
                        class=" x-tree-elbow-img x-tree-elbow-empty"><img
                        src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw=="
                        class=" x-tree-elbow-img x-tree-elbow-plus x-tree-expander"><img
                        src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw=="
                        class=" x-tree-icon x-tree-icon-parent "><span class="x-tree-node-text ">Text to extract 2</span></div>
            </td>
           
            <td role="gridcell"
                class="x-grid-cell x-grid-td x-grid-cell-actioncolumn-1130 x-grid-cell-last x-unselectable  x-action-col-cell"
                id="ext-gen15794">
                <div unselectable="on" class="x-grid-cell-inner x-grid-cell-inner-action-col"
                    style="text-align:left;"><img role="button" alt=""
                        src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw=="
                        class="x-action-col-icon x-action-col-0   x-tree-search"
                        data-qtip="L:eccng.widget.tree_search_tooltip"></div>
            </td>
        </tr>

    </tbody>
```

'''

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out and it works like a charm!   I should've read the instruction manual first, instead of all this trial and error that took all weekend.

```
# Import Selenium items into Python.  I didn't use all these
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver import WebDriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
import time

# Locate and start Chrome Test browser
PATH = "c:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)

# Open website
driver.get("https://your.website.here/index.cfm")

# Give me time to log in
time.sleep(110)

# Go to the correct frame on the page
driver.switch_to.frame("dashboard-frame")


# Start a loop, hopefully a million is long enough
for i in range(1,1000000):

# Find the first node in the nav tree
    datarow = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//tr[@data-recordindex = '"+str(i)+"']")

# Count the number of links to see what level of the tree it's in and print it all out

    hierarchy = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//tr[@data-recordindex = '"+str(i)+"']//img[contains(@src,'data')]")
    level = len(hierarchy) 
    print("Level: " +str(level)+ " " +datarow.text)

# Look for the link to click into the next level of the nav tree.  Need the Try and Except b/c the last level has no links
    try:
 
        link = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//tr[@data-recordindex = '"+str(i)+"']//img[contains(@class,'x-tree-expander')]")
        link.click()

# Wait an ungodly amount of time for the code to populate before moving on.

        time.sleep(10)

# This prints out all the errors, which happens to be the lowest level of tree. Nice surprise.

    except NoSuchElementException:

        print("Point: ")
```

Comment: Instead of the timeout to log in and waiting for the data to load, you could possibly add some fanciness to detect when either action completes, but I doubt the amount of programming involved will be worth it. On the whole, a solution that works is a good solution for incidental scraping - further automation would only be worth it if you needed to run this frequently and possibly unattended.